# Is ext2 inode 5 (EXT2_BOOT_LOADER_INO) used by any operating systems?

Tags: bootloader, ext2

In ext2, there are a number of reserved inodes, such as inode 2 being the root directory. In the [Linux ext2 header file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext2/ext2.h), inode 5 is defined as a "Boot loader inode".

Do any operating systems actually use this?

How do you read from and write to this inode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of reserved inodes can be extracted from the superblock structure from [linux/fs/ext2.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9a3c4145af32125c5ee39c0272662b47307a8323/fs/ext2/ext2.h)

```
/*
* Structure of the super block
*/
struct ext2_super_block {
...
    __le32  s_first_ino;        /* First non-reserved inode */
...
}
```

So the number of reserved inodes is s_first_ino - 1. This number depends on the revision you are using.

The number of the first non-reserved inode for old revision is:

```
/* First non-reserved inode for old ext2 filesystems */
#define EXT2_GOOD_OLD_FIRST_INO 11
```

All the reserved inodes are also defined here:

```
/*
* Special inode numbers
 */
#define EXT2_BAD_INO             1  /* Bad blocks inode */
#define EXT2_ROOT_INO            2  /* Root inode */
#define EXT2_BOOT_LOADER_INO     5  /* Boot loader inode */
#define EXT2_UNDEL_DIR_INO       6  /* Undelete directory inode */
```

EXT2_BOOT_LOADER_INO points to where the bootloader is placed, it is not currently in use. It is just a unused mechanism (until the kernel version 3.10 where its used to swap boot code as you can seee [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2014-01/msg00034.html)) to make easy to place and locate the boot code, so you don't have to search.

As the previous link says, GRUB wants to use EXT2_BOOT_LOADER_INO in the future as a control mechanism:

```
* Support embedding a Stage 1.5 in the EXT2_BOOT_LOADER_INO of an ext2fs
partition, so that it won't be accidentally erased or modified by
the kernel.
```

...even if there was not code at that time to read or modify the inode.